# Is it safe to delete dSYM files on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, file

I've got a few large dSYM files on my machine, installed by the Qt Framework. As I understand they are used for debugging, however I don't actually need to debug the library itself. Is it safe to delete these files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can delete these [debug symbol](http://lldb.llvm.org/symbols.html) files safely. These files provide human readable names for code within the framework or application.

Removing the **dSYM** files will not affect the framework or associated application's ability to run.

## Purpose of a dSYM

Should the calling application or framework crash, the dSYM file is used to provide more readable insight into where the crash occurred in the code.

Apple's [Technical Note 2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151) shows how dSYM files are used – the same approach applies to iOS and Mac OS X.

### dSYM for Developers

Ideally, the developer keeps a copy of the dSYM files and does not distribute these files with their application or frameworks.

When crashes occur, the customer sees a technically obtuse crash report which they can report. The developer can then combine their local dSYM files with the crash report and produce a more readable crash report that should help track down the problem.